# Prove set involving oscillation of function is open (need revision)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, continuity

I need revision of this proof:
Let $D \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be a closed and let $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb R$ a bounded scalar field.

Define oscillation at $\vec{b} \in D$  by

$$  o(f, \vec{b})  = \lim\limits_{\delta \to 0} (M(f, \vec{b}, \delta) - m(f, \vec{b}, \delta) ) $$
Where
$$ M(f, \vec{b}, \delta) = \sup\left\{f(\vec{x}) \;:\; \vec{x} \in  D  \quad\text{and}\quad \left\lVert \vec{x} - \vec{b} \right\lVert \lt \delta \right\} $$
$$ m(f, \vec{b}, \delta) = \inf\left\{f(\vec{x}) \;:\; \vec{x} \in  D  \quad\text{and}\quad \left\lVert \vec{x} - \vec{b} \right\lVert \lt \delta \right\} $$
For some $\lambda \gt 0$ define $A = \left\{\vec{x} \in D \;:\; o(f,\vec{x}) \lt \lambda \right\} $.  **Prove $A$ is open.**

*My attempt of proof:*

Let $\vec{u} \in A$. Then   $o(f,\vec{u}) = \ell$ for some $\ell \lt \lambda$

Now take $\varepsilon = \lambda - \ell \gt 0$. Since the limit equals $\ell$ there exists $\delta_u \gt 0 $ such that

$$\left\lvert M(f, \vec{u}, \delta) - m(f, \vec{u}, \delta) - \ell \right\lvert \lt \varepsilon $$
whenever $\left\lvert \delta \right\lvert \lt \delta_u$. That is 
$$ M(f, \vec{u}, \delta) - m(f, \vec{u}, \delta)  \lt \varepsilon + \ell = \lambda  \quad\text{when}\quad  \left\lVert \vec{x} - \vec{u} \right\lVert \lt \delta \lt \delta_u \tag{1}\label{1}$$

Since we have
$$ M(f, \vec{u}, \delta/2)  -  m(f, \vec{u}, \delta/2)  \le M(f, \vec{u}, \delta)  -  m(f, \vec{u}, \delta) $$

then take $ r = \delta/2$ and consider the ball $B(\vec{u}, r)$. If $ \vec{v} \in B(\vec{u}, r) $ then 
$$ \left\lVert \vec{v} - \vec{u} \right\lVert \lt \delta/2 \lt \delta_u  $$
and 
$$ M(f, \vec{u}, r)  -  m(f, \vec{u}, r)  \le M(f, \vec{u}, \delta)  -  m(f, \vec{u}, \delta) $$

So $\eqref{1}$ holds and $\vec{v} \in A$. Thus, $B(\vec{u}, r) \subseteq A$ and $A$ is open.

Is there something that doesn't make sense or there is a more clear approach for this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your proof uses $\vec{b}$ quite often, but it's never been defined. I suspect you mean $\vec{u}$, and later $\vec{x}$. I don't quite see how you get the strict inequality in the displayed equation after $(1)$ (and again a few lines down). I think it should be "$\le$". Finally, at the end when you claim $(1)$ holds, you skipped some vital steps. You need to show that $M(f,\vec{x},\delta_x)<\lambda$ for some $\delta_x>0$. You seem to have all of the right ideas and are very close.

Comment: @JohnGriffin Thank you. I just fixed the issues with the $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{x}$, sorry about that. Hmm I see, after I claimed $(1)$ holds is when I got more confused. Thanks for your comments.